# Have I incorrectly set up the integral for this center of gravity/centroid problem?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, centroid

> Consider the bounded region R between the graphs of $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = 3x$. Sketch R, which appropriate labels. Then set up all the integrals required do not evaluate.

My solution:

Definitions:

$A = \displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} (f(x) - g(x))dx$

$M_{x} = y-\text{bar} = \frac{1}{A}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{2}(f(x)^{2} - g(x)^{2})dx$

$M_{y} = x-\text{bar} = \frac{1}{A}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} x(f(x) - g(x))dx$

….

$A = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{3} (x^{2} - 3x)dx = \frac{9}{2}$

$M_{x} = y-\text{bar} = \frac{2}{9}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{3} \frac{1}{2}((x^{2})^{2} - (3x)^{2})dx$

$M_{y} = x-\text{bar} = \frac{2}{9}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{3} x(x^{2} - 3x)dx$

The graph was straightforward.
Am not sure if these are right or wrong.
Please help
Thank you

Comment: Your integrand for $A$ and the related expressions are the wrong way round: $3x>x^2$ on $(0,3)$. $M_x$ and $M_y$ labels are also the wrong way round.

Comment: Thank you!
Is this because it's always top function minus bottom function? So first I should have looked at it graphically, and seen that 3x was the top function, therefore it would come first, and x^2 is the bottom function therefore it would come second. Is this right?

Comment: Top minus bottom, yes.

Comment: $A = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{3} (3x - x^{2})dx = \frac{9}{2}$

Comment: Indeed.${}{}{}$

Comment: $M_{x} = y-\text{bar} = \frac{1}{A}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{2}((3x)^{2} - (x^{2})^{2})dx$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thank you

Comment: If you posted an answer I will up vote your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Done.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct integrals should be
$$A=\int_0^3(3x-x^2)\,dx=\frac92$$
$$M_x=\frac29\int_0^3x(3x-x^2)\,dx$$
$$M_y=\frac29\int_0^3\frac{(3x)^2-(x^2)^2}2\,dx$$
since $3x>x^2$ over $(0,3)$.